# An equation for a graph which resembles a hump of a camel / pulse in a string?

Tags: graphing-functions

Sorry if this question isn't valid. I just need to know an equation/function for a graph which resembles something close to 
[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function

Comment: Looks like the "normal distribution curve". Google for it's equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{a}{1+b(x-c)^2}+d$$Looks close to your graph.
Try playing around with the constant to get the desired look
a $\rightarrow$represent the maximum value of your function
 b$\rightarrow$ represents how steep your function is
c$\rightarrow$represents the x co-ordinate of your peak
d$\rightarrow$represents the minima of the function
$$ae^{-b(x-c)^2}+d$$Also looks close to your graph.Constants carry the same meaning

Comment: Thank you! 1/(1+(x+7)^2) gave me exactly what I wanted!